# How to provide name of ivy.xml on command line

Tags: ant, ivy

I have a little sandbox that I use to publish not-invented-here artifacts to our artifact repository.  It has a common build.xml file and a common ivysettings.xml.

I would like to be able to pass the name of the ivy.xml file so I can have exactly one, uniquely-named *someartifact*-ivy.xml file per artifact I intend to publish.

I tried the following:

```
#/bin/sh
ant publish -Divy.settings.file=ivy-external-ivysettings.xml -Divy.dep.file=someartifact-ivy.xml
```

Property `-Divy.settings.file=ivy-external-ivysettings.xml` succeeds in causing ivy to use my `ivy-external-ivysettings.xml` file.

However, ivy seems to ignore property `-Divy.dep.file=someartifact-ivy.xml` and goes looking for `ivy.xml` instead.

The docs suggest to me that my approach should work, as does an upvoted (currently x6) answer to a similar question.

Comment: You should be able to fix this in your Ant script by referencing the Ivy file in the `resolve` task. Something like `<ivy:resolve file="${my.ivy.file}" />` and then pass `-Dmy.ivy.file=my-ivy.xml` in the command line. I don't know if there's a good way to override the default `ivy.dep.file` value.

Comment: Ha!  Why didn't I think of that!  Thanks.